# Отложенная загрузка AngularJS директив

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazyloading

Доброго времени!
Имеется директива А, которая динамически создаёт директиву Б (используя $compile). Директива Б находится в отдельном файле, который подгружается через RequireJS (т.е. на момент работы директивы А, файл с директивой Б уже загружен). Но на выходе вместо ожидаемого результата работы директивы Б имеется только её объявление в HTML. Как необходимо реализовать отложенную загрузку директивы Б?

Answer (score 2):

[Lazy loading directives in AngularJS the easy way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/838402/Lazy-loading-directives-in-AngularJS-the-easy-way)

Т.к. после инициализации приложения создание директив будет невозможно, необходимо сохранить ссылку на compileProvider в объекте приложения.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.config(['$compileProvider', function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
    app.compileProvider = $compileProvider;
}]);
```

Далее создание директивы необходимо вызвать следующим образом:

```
app.compileProvider.directive(...);
```

Аналогично для контроллеров, сервисов и фильтров. Описано в [данной статье.](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-loading-angularjs-components-with-requirejs-after-application-bootstrap.htm)

```
app.config(function( $controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider ) {
...
app.service = function(name, constructor) {
    $provide.service(name, constructor);
    return(this);
};

app.factory = function(name, factory) {
    $provide.factory(name, factory);
    return(this);
};

app.value = function(name, value) {
    $provide.value(name, value);
    return(this);
};
...
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).